# How to get Solana Nfts for owner with Metaplex in React? (Error: 410)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, solana, metaplex, alchemy

I try to get Solana Nfts for owner with Metaplex Javascript SDK but the request gives me the following response:

```
Error: 410 Gone: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code": 410, "message":"The RPC call or parameters have been disabled."}
```

I use React-js framework with hooks.
I can't migrate to Next-js and I don't use typescript.

This is the function that i call. It's a standard function and I copied it from Web:

```
const getNftsForOwnerByAddressAndChainNameSolana = async (address, chainName) => {
  const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl(chainName), "confirmed");
  const keypair = Keypair.generate();
  
  const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection);
  metaplex.use(keypairIdentity(keypair));
  
  const owner = new PublicKey(address);
  const allNFTs = await metaplex.nfts().findAllByOwner({ owner });
  
  console.log(allNFTs);
}
```

Where
chainName = "mainnet-beta";
and address is a real Solana address, that I can explore on official Solana website.

This is the response:

```
Error: 410 Gone: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code": 410, "message":"The RPC call or parameters have been disabled."}
```

I tried to connect to the cluster "devnet". so, chainName = "devnet";
The request has a success response (empty array, no nfts) and the program works, but i need to connect to the cluster "mainnet-beta", because nfts are there.

I also tried this function, that uses Alchemy Api Key:

```
const getNftsForOwnerByAddressAndChainNameSolana = async (address) => {
  const rpc = "https://solana-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/<ALCHEMY_API_KEY>";
  const connection = new Connection(rpc, "confirmed");
  const keypair = Keypair.generate();

  const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection);
  metaplex.use(keypairIdentity(keypair));

  const owner = new PublicKey(address);
  const allNFTs = await metaplex.nfts().findAllByOwner({ owner });
  console.log(allNFTs);
}
```

And it returns an empty array.

You can see that there are nfts on mainnet-beta cluster:
https://explorer.solana.com/address/5VRrCiaczvcHUoRUFz7ZXzR1zpGSCBbU7rndFRYdAFYC/tokens

I searched a lot on web but i didn't find a solution.

How to solve this? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is most likely not even wrong.

`410 Gone` means that the RPC that you are using is not offering the function call that findAllByOwner is using.

Please try using a different RPC to solve this. E.g. Quicknode and [extrnode](https://extrnode.com/) are working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I tried this:

`const rpc = "https://solana-mainnet.rpc.extrnode.com";`

but the result is an empty array.
I also tried this:

`const rpc = "https://solana-mainnet.rpc.extrnode.com/5VRrCiaczvcHUoRUFz7ZXzR1zpGSCBbU7rndFRYdAFYC";`

and the response is:

`Error: 401 : {"message":"invalid api token"}`

How to use extrnode?
I don't want to use Quicknode.

Answer (score 0):

It has changed. Here is how I do it. It gets the json file info you need to use the metadata.

```
import { useConnection, useWallet } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import { Metaplex, walletAdapterIdentity, FindNftsByOwnerOutput, Metadata, JsonMetadata } from "@metaplex-foundation/js";
import { FC, useEffect, useState } from "react";import Container from "../Container/Container";
import NFT from "../NFT/OPENNFTCard"

export const BagGrabber: FC = () => {
  const [nftData, setNftData] = useState<JsonMetadata[]>()
  const [selectedNft, setSelectedNft] = useState<Metadata>();
  const { connection } = useConnection();
  const wallet = useWallet();
  const metaplex = Metaplex.make(connection).use(walletAdapterIdentity(wallet));

  // fetch nfts
  const fetchNfts = async () => {
    if (!wallet.connected) {
      return
    }

    // fetch NFTs for connected wallet
    const NFTs = await metaplex.nfts().findAllByOwner({
      owner: metaplex.identity().publicKey
  });

     // fetch off chain metadata for each NFT
     let counter: number = NFTs.length;
     console.log("counter: "+counter);

    let nftData = [] as unknown as JsonMetadata[];
    let counterI= 0;
    for (var i in NFTs){
    console.log(NFTs[i].uri);
    counterI+=1;
      let fetchResult = await fetch(NFTs[i].uri)
      let json = await fetchResult.json()
      nftData.push(json)
    }

    // set state
    setNftData(nftData);
    console.log(nftData);
  }

  // fetch nfts when connected wallet changes
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchNfts()
  }, [wallet])
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I tried but it doesn't work.
Where can i insert the address? How to setup the owner?
I don't use wallets plugins like Metamask or others and i don't use typescript.

Comment: It looks like you don’t have an RPC provider connected. You can get a free one from Alchemy that provides more than enough service for your project. Have you created an account with them?

Comment: Yes, I have. I have Alchemy Api Key too in Solana network.

Comment: findAllByOwner pulls 50 NFTs, is there a way to pull more?